# Как правильно прописать условия для фильтра?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Имеется фильтр.
Фильтр фильтрует по полю `fio`. Всё работает.
Логика:
- пользователь вводит критерии для фильтра в `<input id="fio">`;
- критерии попадают в JS;
- из БД получают данные;
- строится таблица HTML.

Как настроить фильтр для условий:
- в БД нет данных согласно критериев. Результат: получаем сообщение на странице - `"Нет результатов"`;
- Пользователь очистил `<input id="fio">`. Результат: отображается вся таблица.

Я пробую это сделать, но ничего не происходит.

```
// Фильтр  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
                $('#fio').on('input', function () {
                    var criteria = fio.value;
                    // event.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:2000/players/getByFio",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: { criteria: criteria },
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var html = '';                            
                            var dataState = data.length;                            
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                buildRecords(data);
                            } // if (data.length > 0) {
                            else if (data.length = 0) {                                
                                var html = '';
                            } // if (data.length = 0) { 
                            else if (criteria.length = 0) {
                                loadAllData();
                            } // if (data.length = 1) { 
                            
                        } // success: function (data) {
                    });
                });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Обновление-1

**players.controller.js**

```
exports.getByFio = (req, res) => {
    var criteria = req.body.criteria;
    
    let query = "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE fio LIKE '%" + criteria + "%'"; 

    // execute query
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }           
        res.json(result);        
    });
};
```

**index.ejs**

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script>`

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            load_data();

            // Загрузка-2
            function load_data() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:2000/players/getAll",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { action: 'fetch' },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {
                        buildRecords(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            // Фильтр  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
            $('#fio').on('input', function () {
                var criteria = fio.value;
                // event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:2000/players/getByFio",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { criteria: criteria },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {                                                 
                        var html = '';
                        // let dataState = data.length;
                        var dataState = data.length;
                        
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            buildRecords(data);
                        } // if (data.length > 0) {
                        else if (data.length = 0) {                                
                            var html = '';
                        } // if (data.length = 0) { 
                        else if (criteria.length = 0) {
                            load_data();
                        } // if (data.length = 1) { 

                    } // success: function (data) {
                });
            });

            

            // Построитель таблицы
            function buildRecords(data) {
              var html = '';
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                       html += `
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">`
                            + data[count].id +
                            `</th>
                                <td> 
                                    <img src="/assets/img/` + data[count].image + `"
                                        class="rounded-circle player-img" alt="">
                                </td>
                                 <td>`
                            + data[count].first_name +
                            `</td>
                                <td>`
                            + data[count].last_name +
                            `</td>                                     
                                <td> 
                                    <a id="prisoner" data-id="` + data[count].id + `" href="#"> ` + data[count].fio + `</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>`
                            + data[count].position +
                            `</td>
                                <td>`
                            + data[count].resume +
                            `</td>
                                <td>`
                            + data[count].number +
                            `</td>
                                <td>`
                            + data[count].user_name +
                            `</td>
                                <td> 
                                    <a href="player/edit/` + data[count].id +
                            `" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> Edit </a>
                                    <a href="player/delete/` + data[count].id +
                            `" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> Delete </a>
                                </td>                                                                                                          
                            </tr>
                            `;
                    }
                }

                $('#sample_data tbody').html(html);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недостаточно информации

1. Что и в каком виде возвращает АПИ getByFio в случае, когда criteria пустой и когда туда что-то передано
2. Что такое buildRecords
3. Что такое loadAllData

Но в любом случае, если Вы используете серверную фильтрацию посредством запроса, то всю логику фильтрации следует строить на сервере, а на клиент оставлять только вывод данных

Я бы предложил такую реализацию

1. лучше не кидать запрос на сиюминутное изменение в инпуте, а делать запрос с некоторой задержкой. Это называется debounce, по сути работа с таймером для задержки действий на ввод пользователя. Как реализовать ищите в гугле или на SOF
2. например мы выставили debounce на 500мс. Пользователь вводит что-то в input, через 500мс срабатывает запрос на сервер на getByFio, куда в качестве criteria передается, что ввел пользователь. Причем это же может быть и пустая строка, если пользователь все удалил. Сервер возвращает некий массив данных в зависимости от встроенной логики
3. рендерим таблицу на основе данных, пришедших с сервера (тут уже будут не нужны все те условия, которые Вы понаписали)
4. Profit

Обратите внимание, единичное "=" это присваивание. В условиях IF в JS используйте "==" или еще лучше "===".

Upd: решение:

**#players.controller.js**

```
exports.getByFio = (req, res) => {
    var criteria = req.body.criteria;
    
    let query = "SELECT * FROM 'players'";

    if(criteria){
        query += " WHERE fio LIKE '%" + criteria + "%'"; 
    }

    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }           
        res.json(result);        
    });
};
```

**#index.ejs**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  load_data();
  
    function load_data() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:2000/players/getByFio",
        method: "POST",
        data: { criteria: criteria },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
          buildRecords(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $('#fio').on('input', function () {
      const criteria = $(this).value;
                
            load_data(criteria);
    });
    
    function buildRecords(data) {
      let html = '';
      if (data.length > 0) {
        for (let count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
          html += '<tr>
            <th scope="row">'

            + data[count].id +

            '</th>
              <td>
                <img src="/assets/img/' + data[count].image + '"
                  class="rounded-circle player-img" alt="">
              </td>
            <td>'

            + data[count].first_name +
            
            '</td>
            <td>'
            
            + data[count].last_name +
            
            '</td>                                     
            <td> 
              <a id="prisoner" data-id="' + data[count].id + '" href="#"> ' 
            
            + data[count].fio + 
            
            '</a>
            </td>
            <td>'
            
            + data[count].position +
            
            '</td>
            <td>'
            
            + data[count].resume +
            
            '</td>
            <td>'
            
            + data[count].number +
            
            '</td>
            <td>'
            
            + data[count].user_name +
            
            '</td>
            <td> 
              <a href="player/edit/' 
              + data[count].id +
              '" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> Edit</a>
                <a href="player/delete/' 
                
                + data[count].id +
                
                '" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> Delete </a>
            </td>                
          </tr>';
        }
      }

      $('#sample_data tbody').html(html);
    }
}
```

**Вариант с debounce**

Работоспособность нужно проверять, но логика в целом такая

```
// https://frontend-stuff.com/blog/debounce-in-javascript/
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;

    const later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    const callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

$(document).ready(function () {

  load_data();
  
    function load_data() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:2000/players/getByFio",
        method: "POST",
        data: { criteria: criteria },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
          buildRecords(data);
        }
      });
    }

    const searchDebounce = debounce(function(criteria) {
      load_data(criteria);
    }, 500);

    $('#fio').on('input', function () {
      const criteria = $(this).value;
            searchDebounce(criteria);
    });
    
    function buildRecords(data) {
      let html = '';
      
      // ....тут рендер HTML аналогично первому варианту

      $('#sample_data tbody').html(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: см. **Обновление-1**. Не могли бы вы скорректировать код согласно ваших замечаний... А то я боюсь чего-нибудь не доделать..

Comment: В комментарии не дает вставлять длинный код, ссылка на песочницу https://plnkr.co/edit/mSp2J4HylulScqkl

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку на мой ответ если он Вам помог.

Comment: У меня не совсем получилось... Ну да ладно... Это наверное у меня косяк... В целом заработало кое как. Если вам несложно перенесите код в ответ.... И если совсем несложно реализуйте `debounce`... Спасибо....